# Link Block with :method => :delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

as you may know you can pass a block to the link_to like:

```
<%= link_to new_post_path do %>
html stuff here
<% end %>
```

now my question is if you are able to pass a block to the link_to method with :method => :delete, e.g.

```
<%= link_to @post, :method => :delete, do %>
html stuff here
<% end %>
```

well, i don't know if it is possible... anyone knows more about this or has the correct syntax for it?

already thanks for your answers.

Comment: Have you at least tried it ? ...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are the same.  The path generates the controller:action

You just have an extra comma after delete

```
<%= link_to @post, :method => :delete do %>
   <!-- html stuff here -->
   <div style="height:200px;background-color: red;">
      My Div
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, worked fine this time... don't know why it worked not last time when i tried without the extra comma